# What's the Unity equivalent of StructureMap's For<T>().Use(SomeThing)

Tags: c#, unity-container, structuremap

Assuming I have an instance of `IUnityContainer` to work with, how would I translate this StructureMap `Registry` into Unity?

```
public class MvcRegistry : Registry
{
    public MvcRegistry()
    {
        For<BundleCollection>().Use(BundleTable.Bundles);
        For<RouteCollection>.Use(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

so, for example...

```
public static class UnityContainerExtensions
{
    public static IUnityContainer RegisterMvcComponents(this IUnityContainer container)
    {
        // similar to this:
        container.RegisterType(typeof(BundleCollection), BundleTable.Bundles)
        return container;
    }
}
```

... which isn't right, but you get my meaning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RegisterInstance](https://unitycontainer.github.io/api/Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.html#Unity_UnityContainerExtensions_RegisterInstance__1_Unity_IUnityContainer___0_) method:

```
container.RegisterInstance<BundleCollection>(BundleTable.Bundles)
```